# Xcode compile on NFS: unable to rename temporary .o file

Tags: linux, xcode, macos, nfs, esxi

I am running Xcode to compile modules on NFS volumes, very occasionally I got this error:

```
error: unable to rename temporary 'foo.c.o-d55a0d36' to output file 'foo.c.o': 
'No such file or directory'
```

- Frequency: 0.01% (got 1 error after compiling 10,000 modules)
- Xcode: 6.4 or 7.0
- OS: Mac OS X 10.10
- NFS server (NAS): Debian 7.x (OpenMediaVault 1.x or 2.x)

All the servers (NAS & Mac OS X) are deployed on ESXi host. Actually, I have 2 set of the environments and got similar results.

- Dell R730, RAID 5, ESXi 5.5 U1, Xcode 6.4/Mac OS X 10.10, OpenMediaVault 1.x
- Dell R730, RAID 6, ESXi 6.0 U2, Xcode 7.0/Mac OS X 10.10, OpenMediaVault 2.x

I tried many settings. Current NFS settings:

- Server side: sync,no_subtree_check
- Client side: see the line in /etc/auto_home

`* - fstype=nfs,rw,resvport,proto=tcp,async,intr,nolocks,locallocks,wsize=65536,rsize=65536 nas2:/export/home/&`

Is there any solution for this issue, like

- Change NFS settings? server side or client side.
- Change Mac OS X settings?
- Change Xcode behaviour (No renaming. Why not just compile out to foo.o directly) ?

Could it be a bug of OS X NFS client since the frequency is very low?

Comment: Did you solve it, I encounter the same issue in VirtualBox VM

Comment: Not yet. I just added error detection & retrial. Syncing clock between servers seems help. But I didn't find root cause yet.